# Devise after_sign_in_path_for for other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two separated login model in my rails app:

- User
- Admin

My rake routes output is:
rake routes | grep devise

```
 new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)                                                 devise/sessions#new
                  admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)                                                 devise/sessions#create
          destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format)                                                devise/sessions#destroy
               new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                  devise/sessions#new
                   user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                  devise/sessions#create
           destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                 devise/sessions#destroy
                  user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                 devise/passwords#create
              new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#new
             edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#edit
                                PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                 devise/passwords#update
       cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                   devise/registrations#cancel
              user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                                          devise/registrations#create
          new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                  devise/registrations#new
         edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                     devise/registrations#edit
                                PUT    /users(.:format)                                                          devise/registrations#update
                                DELETE /users(.:format)                                                          devise/registrations#destroy
```

and in ApplicationController i have

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.referrer 
  end
```

It works great for my user model, but how to do it for my admin model, so that after sign in i'm redirected to same page (i use built-in devise controllers) like `after_admin_sign_in_path_for(resource)`
becouse if i write so i have in log:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource
  when User then request.referrer 
  when Admin then ....
  end
end
```

Comment: for when Admin then admin_orders_path  i get undefined method `admin_admin_url' for #<Devise::S....... but i have this route... But when i write when Admin::Admin then admin_orders_path  it's ok, what a strange nesting?

Comment: where did you place :after_sign_in_path_for ?

Comment: did you read my question? 
< ...and in ApplicationController i have... > Also maybe you know: why if admin is signing out, user session is destroyed too?

Comment: i have to see all your devise configuration to answer. But before, try to configure it as there: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: what i can first: i didn't generate any controller, all is gem-build-in... What also you want to see?

Comment: I don't know devise so good. But i guess that your problems with routing are because your devise shares one SessionController for user and admin. You have to split them: Admin::SesssionController and User::SessionController. Then you have to reconfigure routes.rb. Look at the link before...

Comment: i just have to add config.sign_out_all_scopes = false